# Get filtered result from BindingSource to table/dataset?

Tags: c#, combobox, bindingsource

I'm using a `BindingSource` connected to a `DataGridView` to filter the data shown.

I would like to know what is the best way to get the filtered result to some other thing than a GridView?

I ask this as I would like to use the filtered result for a few `ComboBoxes`. Right now I populate these by the DataTable that gets filtered by the BindingSource.

So in short, how do I get filtered BindingSource result as source for something else than a `DataGridView`?

Comment: Please put your sample in as an answer and accept it if it was indeed a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I believe I finally found a solution.

```
sourceDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = bindingSource.Filter;
DataTable destinationDataTable = sourceDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
```